# How to check if time is in range (time range is in string)

Tags: php, mysql, time, datediff

I have a column in my DB , approve_time which contain time range (in String) like 2-3 PM
And I have a time in standard DB format. like 14:17:17
Now I want to check whether this time is in between Database's time range or not.
What should I do ?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Although its easy to write a hack and convert `2-3PM` into a machine readable time range but it is foolish. Why don't you convert that range into a proper time format in your database before you get millions of records and your query takes 5 seconds to execute?

Comment: 5 seconds would be impressive